# addSubviews from xib file contain two or more Custom View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, addsubview

I have `xib` with two `CustomView` (`NSView *one, NSView *two)`,how i `addSubview` in `AppDelegate`?

```
self.content = [[ContentViewController alloc]
                initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController"
                bundle:nil];
[[[[self vertical] subviews] objectAtIndex:1] addSubview:[_content one]];
```

This way don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each view should be in it's own NIB file, as the `NSViewController` only has a single `view` instance variable.

So the answer is to split each view into it's own NIB; set the custom class correctly and then set the *File Owner* to `NSViewContoller` and connect the `view` from the controller to the custom view.

You then load each separately and add their views whereever you like (taking care to keep a reference to the `NSViewController` used to load the view).